# Installing Windows 7 fails on Mountain Lion

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, osx-mountain-lion, boot-camp

### What I want

I'm trying to install Windows 7 with bootcamp(Version 5.0.2 (462)) on Mountain Lion(10.8.3).

### The problem

I get this error message upon opening bootcamp and clicking continue:

```
 The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned.
 You must have at least 10 GB of free space available.
```

;

### What I tried

Based on what I found on the internet:

- Defragmented my disk with [iDefrag](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php)
- Erased free space from my startup disk(Macintosh HD)
- I have around 150GB free space on my startup disk
- I have another disk called DATA which has around 20GB free space only for keeping family photos, applications etc...

[image]

### UPDATE

When I first tried with bootcamp I've got an error I don't really know what it was, but I created a new partition for windows. I thought that would solve it, and since then I got this error, and I can't repartition any of my current partitions, because it says it `can't unload the disk` when I try it from the Recovery tool, when I'm inside the OS it doesn't makes nor says anything. That's why there is an empty gap after the Macintosh HD in the image.

I don't really know what to do but I need to install Windows 7 somehow. Please help me!

Comment: In order to solve this you will need to find a tool to format the unpartition space on your hdd.  The second solution would be to create a new partition using space from the primary partition.

Answer (score 0):

A pedantic person (e.g. me) might point out that the installation does not even occur. This makes your title wrong, which indicates confusion. What "fails" is the preparation tool, or rather your ability to interpret and look up the error.

Often, this happens when newbies *wing it*. The most solid approach is to check the documentation. Of course, the rest of this answer is (also) based on speculation because I have never installed widongs on a schmac. Hopefully the info is useful, and I don't come off as overly offensive.

According to [manuals..apple/bootcamp install](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/boot_camp_install-setup_10.7.pdf) there are a few possible causes.

> If You Have Problems Creating a Partition
>
> If you have problems creating a Windows partition, check the following:
>
> - Your Mac’s disk must be a single partition, formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled).
>     If the disk already has more than one partition, you must repartition it.
> - Your Mac’s disk must be an internal disk. You cannot use Boot Camp Assistant to
>     install Windows on an external disk.
> - If you have a Mac Pro with more than one internal disk and you want to install
>     Boot Camp on a disk that isn’t in the first hard drive bay, remove the drives in the
>     lower numbered bays. You can reinstall the drives after you install Boot Camp.
> - If a dialog appears saying “The disk cannot be partitioned because verification
>     failed,” try repairing the disk using Disk Utility and opening Boot Camp Assistant
>     again. If that doesn’t work, back up all the information on your computer, and
>     reinstall Mac OS X. For more information, click the Finder icon in the Dock, choose
>     Help > Help Center, and search for “reinstall Mac OS X.”

That aside, apparently there is something called "Erase free disk space";

> 1. Go to Disk Utility.
> 2. Select your partiotion (in my case is AdamovHD).
> 3. Go to Erase tab.
> 4. Press the Erase Free Space button.
> 5. Wait the process to be finished.
> 6. Restart your Mac.
> 7. Run BootCamp.
> 8. Install Windows.

References:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634?viewlocale=en_US

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3521241?start=0&tstart=0#jive-17943544944467384478411